# Database normalization - same fields, different tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, normalization

Suppose I have 2 tables. Campaigns and Advertisers. Each of these table has some of the fields exactly same as follows (these is not complete list of fields, I am showing only ones that are same):

**Edit:**
As asked in the comments I will explain more closely relationships.
Each advertiser has 0 to many campaigns. 1 campaign belongs to exactly 1 advertiser. There is another table, let's call it "Offer". When new offer is created, all of the counts columns needs to be increased (campaigns.monthly_count, campaigns.total_count, advertisers.monthly_count, advertisers.total_count). Limits columns are specific caps which the counts columns cannot exceed.

**campaigns**

```
monthly_limit (int)
total_limit (int)
monthly_count (int)
total_count (int)
```

**advertisers**

```
monthly_limit (int)
total_limit (int)
monthly_count (int)
total_count (int)
```

Question is: **Is it normalized database design or is there better way to do things?**

I was thinking about having another table like this:

**limits**

```
campaign_id (int)
advertiser_id (int)
monthly_limit (int)
total_limit (int)
monthly_count (int)
total_count (int)
```

But this way one of the referenced columns would be always empty and I cannot use foreign keys.

Or another option probably is something like this:

**limits_campaigns**

```
campaign_id (int)
monthly_limit (int)
total_limit (int)
monthly_count (int)
total_count (int)
```

**limits_advertisers**

```
advertiser_id (int)
monthly_limit (int)
total_limit (int)
monthly_count (int)
total_count (int)
```

This way I would have to write probably lot more joins in the queries but I could use foreign keys.

**Is there any other option which seems more appropriate and if not which of these designs is the best?**

P.S.: Just to be more specific I am using MySQL InnoDB engine.

Comment: In my experience it depends on the user interface and model needs. We de-normalized a database which actually sped up the application because it cut out many extensive joins. Normalization is just what should normally be done but not what has to be done. Run test for yourself and see which performs better and try to look down the road for any project scope that may creep in and change this at a later date which sometimes is completely impossible

Comment: Could you explain better your scenario? It is necessary to understand better the relationship between those tables. Should it be a one-to-many relationship between campaign and advertiser?. Could the advertiser participate in one or more campaigns making the relationship a many-to-many?. What about those "limits". Is the campaign limit different of the advertiser limit?

Comment: @Javier I have update the question with more details.

Comment: in limits_campaigns and limits_advertisers use limits_id to reference the limits table do not repeat your attribute  in two tables

Answer (score 1):

There will be another approach: 
Having a base table called `limitable-entity`(my naming is not satisfying) with one-to-on relation to campaign and advertiser.
limitable-entity will be the implementation of [generalization pattern in database design](http://books.google.com/books?id=2hM3-xxZC-8C&pg=PA127&lpg=PA127&dq=Common%20Patterns%20of%20Table%20and%20Database%20Predicates&source=bl&ots=VfQrtHiW6V&sig=TTLB6R6yN13VpsB_ylrgeYCntUI&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ljSnUuyiC8nAtAbyo4DwDg&ved=0CCgQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=Common%20Patterns%20of%20Table%20and%20Database%20Predicates&f=false).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As you have found out yourself, doing it this way:

```
campaign_id (int)
advertiser_id (int)
monthly_limit (int)
total_limit (int)
monthly_count (int)
total_count (int)
```

You have two primary keys. That's not possible even when you just use campaign_id as primary key, because of the not null and/or unique constraint of a primary key.

What you can use is a composite primary key:

```
item_id (int)
item_type (int)
monthly_limit (int)
total_limit (int)
monthly_count (int)
total_count (int)

primary key(item_id, item_type)
```

Then you can have a reference table 
Ref_Item_Type:

```
1 campaign
2 advertiser
3 whatever
N ...
```

Then you can reference the composite primary key as foreign key, and you won't have to do any join / union if you want to get all items.

```
CREATE TABLE SecondaryTable (
  AutoID int,
  Key1 int,
  Key2 int
)


ALTER TABLE SecondaryTable 
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Whatever FOREIGN KEY (Key1, Key2) REFERENCES PrimaryTable (item_id, item_type)
```

Comment: Not sure if this is specific for my question as I have 2 tables. In your query example you are making foreign key which is referencing 2 columns in one table. Is it possible to reference 1 column from each table? Edit: now I see what you have done, introduced one more table.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments:

Table advertisers:

```
advertiser_id PK
monthly_limit (int)
total_limit (int)
monthly_count (int)
total_count (int)
```

Table campaigns, with reference to the advertiser in which it belongs

```
campaign_id PK
advertiser_id FK
monthly_limit (int)
total_limit (int)
monthly_count (int)
total_count (int)
```

About the counts, you should control that with your business logic.